# How to intersect more than two layers? Is there a quick way?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, geoprocessing, intersection

We have three layers, income, obesity and fast food restaurants for England and we wanted to find districts where they all intercepted. So we did a combination of two layers at a time to find where all three crossed over, but is there a quicker way of doing this in one step??

Comment: Does the [Intersect tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000000p000000) not do the trick?

Comment: Could you please update your post to include which licensing you have?  FYI, you may be better off using QGIS if your ArcGIS license is not sufficient.

Answer (score 4):

With ArcGIS for Desktop Basic and Standard licenses, the number of input feature classes or layers is limited to two. (source: arcgis help)

So if you don't have the advanced license, you need to run the tool twice. If you want to have the intersect tool for three layers because you will often need it, you can use model builder to make your own reusable "three layer intersect" tool.